# Error while reading excel file in selenium

Tags: java, excel

```
package ReadExcelData;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadandWriteExcel {

 public static void main(String []args){

  try {
      File src = new File("C:\\poi\\ExcelData\\TestExcelData.xlsx");
      FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);

      XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
      XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);
      System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
      System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
      System.out.println(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
      System.out.println(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
      System.out.println(sh1.getRow(2).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
      System.out.println(sh1.getRow(2).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
      wb.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }
```

}

Hi,

I Downloaded poi-4.0.0 and added external jar file to my project. After setup of project I created excel file and wrote java program to read from excel file

```
While run time I am getting error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:298)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
    at ReadExcelData.ReadandWriteExcel.main(ReadandWriteExcel.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more`enter code here`
```

Comment: Removed the selenium tag since it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Your Excel file is the newer format, `.xlsx`. Change it to the older format, `.xls`, and try again.

Comment: Hi JeffC,I tried but still same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add commons-compress-1.18.jar into your project build path.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/download_compress.cgi